# Cppcheck is returning different results on each scan

Tags: c, cortex-m, cppcheck

I'm trying to check embedded C code using Cppcheck (running on Windows 7, using GUI) but every time I click on "Reanalyze all files" I get different results.
The code is meaned to get build using GCC and running on a cortex M4 controller (STM32F4)

I set the Paths and include paths (here only the root folder of our code, the includes are in several sub directories) and copied the global defines from our project. I tried different platforms (Windows-XX, Unix-XX, Unix-XX-Unsigned as I could not find one more fitting to cortex M4) all with the same result.

Is this some kind of misconfiguration? I tried this with an older version about a year ago and got frustrated about the exact same error so stopped using it back then but want to give it a try again.

Here are parts of `statistics.txt`: (all I did here is clicking "Reanalyze all files" over and over again)

```ini
[03.04.2019]
1554274191556
cppcheck-error:0
cppcheck-warning:1
cppcheck-style:173
cppcheck-performance:0
cppcheck-portability:0
[03.04.2019]
1554274506334
cppcheck-error:0
cppcheck-warning:0
cppcheck-style:3
cppcheck-performance:0
cppcheck-portability:0
[03.04.2019]
1554274517988
cppcheck-error:0
cppcheck-warning:0
cppcheck-style:25
cppcheck-performance:0
cppcheck-portability:0
[03.04.2019]
1554274520320  //not a single error found here, so nothing got logged
[03.04.2019]
1554274523893
cppcheck-error:0
cppcheck-warning:1
cppcheck-style:3
cppcheck-performance:0
cppcheck-portability:0
[03.04.2019]
1554274524825
cppcheck-error:0
cppcheck-warning:2
cppcheck-style:36
cppcheck-performance:0
cppcheck-portability:0
[03.04.2019]
1554274526116  //not a single error found here, so nothing got logged
```

Comment: Must be some strange kind of incorrect configuration. I use `cppcheck` version 1.82 on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) regularly, and results are 100% reproducible.